# How to i create audio waveform like messenger and WhatsApp, suggest me some packages. I want to customize it as i want

Tags: react-native, avaudioplayer, react-android, audiowaveform

I create audio waveform like messenger and WhatsApp.
when I sent any recorded voice it should be looking similer to the messenger or WhatsApp.

I already tried
react-native-audiowaveform

this package but i am getting error.
Error: Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "OGWave" was not found in the UIManager.
Now what should i do?